# using arraylist inside mysql select statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a login `arraylist` where i have stored users loginid using following mysql query

Code:

```
query = "select LoginID from issuedeposit id where id.DueDate < CURDATE()";

    result = statement.executeQuery(query);

    while(result.next())
    {
        String loginid = result.getString(1);
        loginarray.add(loginid);
    }
```

now I want to use the loginid values stored in the `above arraylist` to fetch users emailid form `other` table. I am using following query

Code:

```
 for(int i=0;i<=loginarray.size();i++)
    {

        res = statement1.executeQuery("select EmailID form studentaccount sa where sa.LoginID = '"+ loginarray.get(i) +"' ");

        String email = res.getString(1);
        emailarray.add(email);       

    }
```

but am getting error in the above query. So have i correctly used the `for loop` or it should be used inside the query...?
 I am using JDBC and MySql

Comment: You have already got the answers. I would suggest to try prepared statements and bind variables. A quick starting point is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687550/preparedstatements-and-performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = statement1.executeQuery("select EmailID form studentaccount sa 
where sa.LoginID = '"+ loginarray.get(i) +"' ");
```

Should be

```
res = statement1.executeQuery("select EmailID FROM studentaccount sa 
where sa.LoginID = '"+ loginarray.get(i) +"' ");
```